# Chrome does load video file once, but not twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, video

I am loading and autostarting a couple of video's on a webpage. They are embedded using the HTML5 video tag. When I click on one of the video's, they are opened again, but now in a bigger screen. Firefox plays the second video fine, but Chrome doesn't load the second one.

I guess the problem is that Chrome doesn't want to play one video twice simultaneously. What is the reason, and is there a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

Chrome only opens one connection to the server to download a resource.  Once the first video is opened all subsequent connections will be ignored until that connection is closed.  And it seems it leaves connections to mp4's (and possibly other video types) open for some reason, maybe for streaming?

Even on separate tabs or websites, if the resource is the same it will not load.  One method may be to destroy the video on the current page, then open it in the new window.